# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. (for .NET Framework 4.5)

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am developing an application with ASP.NET and Oracle 10g.

Setup of my local PC:

```
Windows 7 Professional
Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (.Net framework 4.5)
Install Oracle Client (Version 10.2.0.3.0) 
which gives the Oracle.DataAcess.dll (Version  1.102.3.0)
connect to database server Oracle.
```

but when I connect but give the error message provided by

```
DbProviderFactory factory = 
                   DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");
```

please help me how to configure .NET framework and Oracle Client as early as possible.

Thanking 
Shohel

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should check:

1. Do the assembly architectures of the application and ODP.NET match? ODP.NET has different assemblies for 64- and 32-bit. You should check you installed the correct version (or install both);
2. Check that the Oracle.DataAccess.Client file is in the Assembly cache (GAC);
3. Check that machine.config file contains the Oracle.DataAccess.Client provider settings.

   It should contain something like this:

   ```
   <section name="oracle.dataaccess.client"
            type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
   />
   ```

Just as a hint, take a look at the new Oracle provider that is both 64- and 32-bit compatible and that does not need Oracle client to be installed, it is called [ODP.NET Managed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)!

Comment: @user3673514: Need more help? Is your problem solved already?